# Mercurial Merge

Tags: mercurial, merge

A coworker merged a bunch of files that broke the build.  I need to revert back to a working version and then commit that version in.  I want to do the whole tree.

To get Reversion:
"Hg update 4"  This will retrive the reversion 4 of the files.

I'm not sure how I would commit the changes and erase whatever was checked in.

Note: It would take too long to go to each file and do a merge, so i'm looking to revert the whole tree.

I'm also using tortoise HG.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hg up -r 4
<some edits>
hg ci -m "This is correct"
hg push -f
```